# how to view sql for a metric in microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

How do i view the sql for a metric that is being used in a microstrategy dashboard?

I am trying to extract all the business logic that is stored in the microstrategy dashboard/cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two types of metrics- regular microstrategy metric- for which sql is generated; other derived metric calculated from other regular metrics

I am assuming you have a cube- and you have regular metric
Create a grid report from the cube with just the metric and the attributes shown in the dashboard and view the sql.

If value shown in the grid report(non cube) does not match with one in dashboard.. issue is with dynamic aggregation

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to see the metric's sql is with a report in MSTR Desktop/Developer, with "View SQL/MDX" right click context menu option (you can display this view from menu or icon bar in edit mode too). This works with cubes too.

Of course, you need to build a report with exactly the same attribs and configuration (VLDBs, join types, etc.) as the grid you are displaying in your dashboard, if you don't have this one alone. From a cube you already have the right SQL.

With embedded in reports/docs, just copy the formula into an external one and repeat the steps above.

Derived metrics are calculated by the Analityc Engine from its components as a final step in the report/cube's execution. In this case you can only check the component's SQL.

Regards!